# Pass initialValue as prop to redux-form field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

There are lots of documents for redux-form, but none so far have helped with my particular setup.

**End goal story**

I want to pre-fill a profile form, eventually allowing data to be changed and sent back via the API.

**Progress so far...**

I can get the form to be pre-filled with static values in the form.js file. The next step is to replace these static values with the fetched data for that profile. I have the data ready and available for the profile on the index, I now need to pass this to the form.js and replace the static `initialValues`. However, the way the form.js file is structured its not as obvious to me how to pass this "prop" onto the `initialValues` tag.

**INDEX.JS**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./store";
import MyForm from "./form";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { whenGapiReady } from 'util/gapiHelper';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { fetchProfile } from 'actions/PlayerProfile';

class UserProfilePage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    static propTypes = {
        playerId: PropTypes.string
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.handleInitialize();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        whenGapiReady(() => {
            const { fetchProfile } = this.props;
            const { playerId } = this.props.match.params;
            fetchProfile(playerId);
        });
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
        if (this.props.hasOwnProperty('profile')) {
            if (this.props.profile.playerId !== prevProps.profile.playerId) {
                // We only really need to reload the player if the playerId has changed
            }
        }
    }

    render() {

        const { playerId } = this.props.match.params;
        const { profile } = this.props;

        if (!playerId) {
            return null;
        }

        return (

            <Provider store={store}>                           
                <MyForm fullName={profile.fullName} />
            </Provider>

        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ playerProfile, settings }) => {
    const { loader, profile, profileError } = playerProfile;
    const { darkTheme } = settings;
    return { loader, profile, profileError, darkTheme };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchProfile })(UserProfilePage);
```

As you can see from above I am trying to pass the profile name here:

```
<MyForm fullName={profile.fullName} />
```

**FORM.JS**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { reduxForm, Field, FieldArray } from "redux-form";

const renderfirstName = ({ fields }) => (
  <div>
    <h3>Player Profile:</h3>
    {fields.map((playerProfile, index) => (
      <div>
        <Field name={playerProfile} key={index} component="input" />
      </div>
    ))}
    <button type="button" onClick={() => fields.push()}>Add more</button>
  </div>
);
const MyForm = ({ handleSubmit, fullName }) => (
  <form onSubmit={ handleSubmit } initialValues={{fullName: fullName}}>
    <FieldArray name="fullName" component={renderfirstName} />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
);
export default reduxForm({

  form: "foo",
  enableReinitialize: true,
  onSubmit: values => {
    window.alert( "Submited: \n" + JSON.stringify( values, null, 2 ) );
  }
})( MyForm );
```

I tried adding the `initialValues` tag directly onto the `<form>` tag:

```
<form onSubmit={ handleSubmit } initialValues={{fullName: fullName}}>
```

But initially I had the `initialValues` in the export like this:

```
export default reduxForm({
  form: "foo",
  initialValues: {
    playerProfiles: ['Tom Rudge']
  },
  onSubmit: values => {
    window.alert( "Submited: \n" + JSON.stringify( values, null, 2 ) );
  }
})( MyForm );
```

With the initialValues set in the form.js export the form is pre-populated with the static value, its just getting that fetched value onto the form from its parent index that seems to be the issue. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so managed to work it out, hopefully this will help somebody else - and so I can reference back if I need to

**INDEX.JS**

```
<Provider store={store}>                           
     <MyForm initialValues={{fullName:[profile.fullName]}} />
</Provider>
```

Pass the InitialValue at component level.

**FORM.JS**

```
  <form onSubmit={ handleSubmit }>
    <FieldArray name="fullName" component={renderfirstName} />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Remove any other `initialValues` at form level

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for a solution that includes react-redux, you can pull from props in the following manner.

Using [mapStateToProps](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate#defining-mapstatetoprops), make sure to pass ownProps as the second argument. You can then return an initialValues object that links your props to your form names, like so

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return {
    initialValues: { formName: ownProps.propsValue }
  };
}
```